# Small caps with lmodern font not shown in epub via tex4ebook

Tags: small-caps, tex4ebook, lmodern

Try this following MWE and run tex4ebook, you will find that small caps are ignored in this epub. 1. Why? And 2. how to make it happen?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\textsc{A sentence with small caps of lmodern font, which is not showed in epub}

\end{document}
```

**Update 1**

When I use the `.htf` file that is shown in the first answer, small caps are respected when viewed with calibre ebook reader. But the **size settings** seem to be ignored. For example things like `\textsc{\Huge Huge Text}` or `{\scshape\Huge Huge Text}` seem to be ignored in the epub file when viewed with calibre. Thank you for suggestions how to fix this. The MWE for this detection is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
%\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\textsc{A sentence with small caps text of lmodern font, which is shown in epub when using the fonts option}

\Huge\textsc{Huge text in small caps is ignored when viewed in callibre with lmodern}

\begin{center}
\normalsize\scshape Another sentence with scshape command where sc is ignored in callibre\\
\LARGE LARGE text in small caps is respected but sc is ignored when viewed in callibre with lmodern
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Always run `tex4ebook sample.tex "fonts"`.

The Update 1 question would be: Why is the **relative** order of size settings, which appear in the `.tex` file not respected via `tex4ebook` in the `.epub` file when viewed with calibre? To be precise: It should appear a solvable task to respect the **relative order** of `\footnotesize` and `\normalsize` and `\large` and `\Huge` (which are used in a `.tex` file) to be respected in the `.epub` file. Is my question out of scope? Or is it solvable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is an error in the font configuration file for Latin Modern fonts, so the information about small caps is not transferred to the CSS file. The correct file is this one, `ec-lm.htf`:

```
.lm-ec
htfcss: ec-lmbo  font-style: oblique;
htfcss: ec-lmbx  font-weight: bold;
htfcss: ec-lmbxi  font-style:italic; font-weight: bold;
htfcss: ec-lmbxo  font-style: oblique; font-weight: bold;
htfcss: ec-lmcsco  font-style: oblique;
htfcss: ec-lmcs  font-variant: small-caps;
htfcss: ec-lmcsc  font-variant: small-caps;
htfcss: ec-lmri  font-style:italic;
htfcss: ec-lmro  font-style: oblique;
htfcss: ec-lmss  font-family: sans-serif;
htfcss: ec-lmssbo  font-family: sans-serif; font-style: oblique; font-weight: bold;
htfcss: ec-lmssbx  font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
htfcss: ec-lmssdc  font-family: sans-serif;
htfcss: ec-lmssdo  font-family: sans-serif; font-style: oblique;
htfcss: ec-lmsso  font-family: sans-serif; font-style: oblique;
htfcss: ec-lmssq  font-family: sans-serif;
htfcss: ec-lmssqbo  font-family: sans-serif; font-style: oblique; font-weight: bold;
htfcss: ec-lmssqbx  font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
htfcss: ec-lmssqo  font-family: sans-serif; font-style: oblique;
htfcss: ec-lmtcsc  font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmtcso  font-style: oblique; font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmtk  font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmtko  font-style: oblique; font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmtl  font-weight: light; font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmtlc  font-weight: light; font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmtlco  font-weight: light; font-style: oblique; font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmtlo  font-weight: light; font-style: oblique; font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmtt  font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmtti  font-family: monospace,monospace; font-style:italic;
htfcss: ec-lmtto  font-style: oblique; font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmvtk  font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmvtko  font-style: oblique; font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmvtl  font-weight: light; font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmvtlo  font-weight: light; font-style: oblique; font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmvtt  font-family: monospace,monospace;
htfcss: ec-lmvtto  font-style: oblique; font-family: monospace,monospace;
```

Alternatively, you can use the "fonts" option, which will use HTML markup for fonts:

```
$ tex4ebook sample.tex "fonts"
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Michal. I will look this evening for your solution if it works on my system. I thought this might me a problem of different ebook reader performance, that some interpret small caps as normal font and only display normalfonts and italic and omit small caps. Your answer: The `"fonts"` option needs to be added with run of tex4ebook? Including " " signs? I think I have to read the documentation of tex4ebook to see what else there can be possible.

Comment: @Thomkrates the `"fonts"` option is better in your case because bold and italics should work even in Epub readers without CSS support. Small-caps have no particular element in HTML, so it always depends on the CSS support. You can find information about options here: https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/texfourhtOptions.html

Comment: Ok., I will look at it. My `.tex` files do not use any bold fonts, no `\textbf`, no `\bfseries`. But only `\scshape, and \textsc{}`  and `\emph`. `\textit{}` or `\rmfamily, and \textrm{}, \normalfont`. `sc` for the chapter titles and headings, `emph` and `it` for Quotations and the normal `rm` for the main and ordinary text content. If I understand you right, it would give the best results for epub and epub readers to use the `"fonts"` option? And there is no another way to force ebook readers to display small caps? Only through css support?

Comment: @Thomkrates If you use only these commands, then it will take most of the information from CSS, so the updated `.htf` file is necessary.

Comment: Ok. But originally I like to use `ebgaramond fonts` (not lmodern) for both my pdf prints and epub files.  And with them I had error messages, when using small caps and `\textsc{] or \shshape` and generating `.epub files`. So is there a possibility to get correct output in `epub` (and to get an output at all), using `corrected .htf files` for `ebgaramond fonts`? In an earlier error message runnig tex4ebook it concerned `EBGaramond-Regular-lf-ts1.htf` this file obviolusly. Since when I changed to lmodern, this error disappeared.

Comment: With `lmodern` and the option `"fonts"` with tex4ebook, I find that in calibre reader the small caps are shown with `\textsc{}` but not with `\scshape`. And without this option no small caps are shown at all in calibre, instead normalfonts rm. In Adobe Digital Edition also nothing happens concering the small caps, independent to the option `"fonts"`.

Comment: @Thomkrates and in HTML it works? Do you use the HTF file? Regarding ADE, maybe it uses font with no small caps support. It is possible to select a different font?

Comment: Yes, I used the above file, and overwrote the existing one `ec-lm.htf` in TeXLive 2023. The result is, that in `calibre` both `\textsc{Some text}` and ``\scshape Text` are shown as small caps, which did not show up before this file change. And in tex4ebook run I did then not use the option `"fonts"` only the file change. - With my favourite `ebgaramond` font calibre will show the same result concerning the small caps as now is said with `lmodern` and the changed `.htf` file.

Comment: I added Update 1, with MWE and a question cocerning the ***relativ size order** and the mapping between ``.tex` and `.epub`. Thank you for caring.

Comment: @Thomkrates I've tried your updated example, and Calibre shows correct font sizes and small caps.

Comment: Ok, thank you, Michal. a least on your system. Good - but still strange to me appearing. I need to look at it  this evening again. On my system it yet did not work, maybe there is still a texlive update to be done. I did some `tlmgr update tex4ht` yesterday evening.

Comment: I updated now tex4ht. The result: `\Huge` and `\huge` will be (for `small caps`) in `lmodern ignored` when viewed in calibre, but `\LARGE` is respected for small caps in calibre. Is this also your finding, Michal? Or is there a way for me to get both `\Huge` and `\huge` to be respected in this case?

Comment: @Thomkrates no, for me the sizes are correct